# regex to capture: word_{word}_word

Tags: regex

I have entries like this:

```
media_voice_message
media_photo
media_audio_file
media_video
```

I want to capture only the words in the middle, so that the output be like:

```
voice
photo
audio
video
```

I tried this regex:

```
/media_(\w+)(_\w+)?/
```

and this:

```
/media_([\w^_]+)/
```

But the output for both of these is:

```
voice_message
photo
audio_file
video
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Try: `^media_([^_\s]+)(?:_\w+)?$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those middle words are only letters `[a-z]`, then this simple pattern would work:

```
media_([a-z]+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/QdQ7zv/3

Answer (score 0):

You can capture middle word with a regex:

```
  /^media_(\w+?)(?:_|$)/
```

https://regex101.com/r/QdQ7zv/4

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this expression for instance might work:

```
^(?:[^_]*_)([^_]*)(?=_|$)
```

#### [DEMO 1](https://regex101.com/r/AuTIex/1/)

Or more bounded, this one:

```
^(?:media_)([^_]*)(?=_|$)
```

#### [DEMO 2](https://regex101.com/r/ghCSv5/1/)